# Crystal Report Viewer Error

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Using C# windows Forms application I'm generating a crystal report using following code.

```
        private void frmReportViewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument())
        {
            string a = (new System.Uri(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase)).AbsolutePath;
            string b = Path.GetDirectoryName(a);
            string fullPath = Path.Combine(b, "..\\..\\Reports\\DailyAttendance\\rpt_DailyAttendance.rpt");

            DataSet ds_attendance = new DataSet();
            ds_attendance = obj_dalTimeAttendance.getAttendanceReport();
            ds_attendance.Tables[0].TableName = "RPT_TIMESHEET";

            report.Load(fullPath);
            report.SetDataSource(ds_attendance);
            report.SetDatabaseLogon("cil_hr", "asd@123");
            rptViewer.ReportSource = report;
            rptViewer.DisplayToolbar = true;
            rptViewer.RefreshReport();
        }
    }
```

Report loading without the issue. But when I'm clicking on tool bar buttons in report viewer attached error showing. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Yes, DataSet getting data and report loading with data.

Comment: What is the code that surrounds this? it could very well be something you are not showing here

Comment: Question edited.Please check